# .Net StreamWriter.BaseStream, what does this definition mean? "Gets the underlying stream that interfaces with a backing store."

Tags: c#, .net, stream, streamwriter

I was reading about `StreamWriter` today, and came across this property, `BaseStream`.

I was looking for a definition and found this

> "Gets the underlying stream that interfaces with a backing store."

from here [MSDN - StreamWriter.BaseStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.basestream.aspx)

I understand what a BaseStream is for StreamReader, because it's definition is very simply:

> Returns the underlying stream.

But what does the definition of the StreamWriter.BaseStream mean?? Or more clearly, what does this part of the definition mean "interfaces with a backing store"? That sounds like gibberish to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right; it does seem unnecessarily wordy, especially in comparison with the analogous `StreamReader.BaseStream`. In reality, it just returns a reference to the underlying stream, exactly like StreamReader.

I think the presumption of the description is that writing to the underlying stream will involve saving the written data to some sort of persistent store, such as a file. Of course, this isn't necessary at all in reality (in the worst case, it could simply do nothing).

If you *really* wanted to extrapolate, you could interpret that as meaning that the underlying stream's `CanWrite` property is `true` (at least at the point it was attached to the StreamWriter).

---

To be convinced that it really is just returning the underlying stream, here's the decompiled code from Reflector:

```
public virtual Stream BaseStream
{
    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
    get
    {
        return this.stream;
    }
}
```

where the `stream` field is assigned in the `Init` method:

```
private void Init(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize)
{
    this.stream = stream;
   ...
```

which in turn is called by the constructor with the argument being the *attached* stream:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public StreamWriter(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize) 
  : base(null)
{
    ...
    this.Init(stream, encoding, bufferSize);
}
```

---

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now . . . thanks. So it's a two part definition . . . 1. The underlying Stream and 2. Oh by the way, it's a stream that interfaces with some sort of persistent data store. #2 is a bit redundant, since this IS a StreamWriter object after all. Very wordy indeed. Thank you.

Comment: @Richard DesLonde: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

So the generic definition of `Stream` is this:

> Provides a generic view of a sequence
>   of bytes.

and `StreamWriter`:

> Implements a TextWriter for writing
>   characters to a stream in a particular
>   encoding.

So the `BaseStream` property is where the characters will be written to. This may be a `FileStream` or a `MemoryStream` or anything else that implements `Stream`. I feel like a better description would be:

> Gets the underlying stream.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is for when you "daisychain" streams.

Eg your code writes to stream A, which writes to stream B, which writes to stream C, which writes to disk.

Stream A's basestream is B in that instance.

Comment: I understand the concept I think, that it is the base stream, but I am really wondering what "interfaces with a backing store" means. That doesn't make any sense to me. I don't understand those words at all.