# Write only stream - get written bytes count with DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, stream, datacontractserializer

Consider I have the following snippet:

```
public void Store(Stream s, object t)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(target.GetType(),
                                            new DataContractSerializerSettings
                                            {
                                                PreserveObjectReferences = true
                                            });

    serializer.WriteObject(s, target);
}
```

where `s` is **write-only** and **doesn't support seeking**.

Is there any way to get bytes count that was written to stream by `WriteObject`? I know I can do it in the following way:

```
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.WriteObject(serializer, target);
    Debug.WriteLine(memStream.Length);
    memStream.CopyTo(s);
}
```

but I wonder wheter it is possible to avoid `CopyTo` - object is quite huge.

**EDIT:**
I've just came up with an idea: I can create a wrapper that counts bytes on write. It's the best solution so fat, but maybe there is another way.

**DONE**

I've implemented a wrapper: https://github.com/pwasiewicz/counted-stream - maybe it will be useful for someone.

Thanks!

Comment: s.Length ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @PaulZahra As I have written, `s` is write-only and doesn't support seeking so accessing `Length` throws `NotSupportedException` exception.

Comment: Yeah, you should build a stream wrapper / decorator that tracks the number of incoming bytes.

Comment: Your idea about `Stream`-derived wrapper is OK. I'd implement it.

Comment: @pwas Have you tried s.BaseStream.Length ?

Comment: @PaulZahra there is no BaseStream inside `Stream`. Such a property is in `StreamReader` rather. Thanks to other, I will implement a wrapper.

Comment: @pwas streamwriter.basestream https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.basestream.aspx also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653543/net-streamwriter-basestream-what-does-this-definition-mean-gets-the-underlyi

Comment: @PaulZahra yep, but I have only `Stream`, not a `StreamWriter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample implementation of a wrapper I've made:

```
public class CountedStream : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream stream;
    public CountedStream(Stream stream)
    {
        if (stream == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");

        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public long WrittenBytes { get; private set; }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        this.stream.Flush();
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return this.stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return this.stream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        this.stream.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (buffer.Length >= offset + count)
                     throw new ArgumentException("Count exceeds buffer size");
        this.stream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        this.WrittenBytes += count;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return this.stream.CanRead; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return this.stream.CanSeek; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return this.stream.CanWrite; }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return this.stream.Length; }
    }

    public override bool CanTimeout
    {
        get { return this.stream.CanTimeout; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { return this.stream.Position; }
        set { this.stream.Position = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi -- thanks for this. But isn't `if (buffer.Length >= offset + count)` the wrong way round?